# Xamarin step by step wizard android views

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I want to build an android activity in Xamarin c# for step by step registration and/or information. How can I do something like this:

[image]

Can anyone give me a code sample or anything? Thanks.

Comment: Additional information: Every dot is a registration page.

Comment: Sorry for not replying. I didn't forget you. :) I'll try to show you a sample of what to do in the next couple of days.

Comment: Hi Amitairos, I'm also trying to implement it but my visual studio is going nuts. So I'm trying to fix that also. But thank you for your answer and your effort to help me. I will be waiting for your sample.

Comment: I updated my answer with a full explanation. If you encounter any problems, feel free to ask.

Comment: Did you manage to fix your Visual Studio? Did you see my answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically you need to use an element called a `ViewPager`, and every page will be a different `Fragment`. You can use [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/ViewPagerIndicator/) library to help you. Feel free to ask questions and guidance.

**Edit - Detailed explanation:**
Add two images to your drawable folder- one of the unselected dot, and one of the selected dot.
Add these two NuGet packages (Right-Click your project in the Solution Explorer, click Manage NuGet Packages, and search): Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 and Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat.

Then your Main.axml layout, put this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat"
      app:titleMarginTop="15dp"/>
  <FrameLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
       android:id="@+id/viewPager"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <LinearLayout
               android:id="@+id/viewPagerCountDots"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
               android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
               android:orientation="horizontal">
      <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ViewPagerDotSelected"/>
      <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ViewPagerDotUnselected"/>
      <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ViewPagerDotUnselected"/>
    </LinearLayout>
  </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

You can play around with the width, the height, and the margin later.

Next, create new Fragments that will each contain your different pages (or "steps"). For this example, I created three.

Do this three times, while changing the name of the files and their contents:
Right-Click Project >> Add >> New Item >> Fragment, post the following code as an example:

```
public class Fragment1 : Fragment
{
    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Fragment1Layout, container, false);

        //Here goes what you want to do within the fragment.

        return view;
    }
}
```

Replace the names of the class and layouts for each fragment.

Then Right-Click on your layout folder >> Add New Item >> Android Layout.
Post the following code as an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="FRAGMENT 1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Do this three times while changing the name and contents.

Now, in you MainActivity.cs, post the following code after your Namespace name:

```
 [Activity(Label = "ViewPagerIndicator", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar")]
 public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
 {

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        var toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        SupportActionBar.Title = "ViewPager Indicator Dots";

        var pager = new ViewPagerAdapter(SupportFragmentManager);
        var viewPager = FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewPager);
        viewPager.Adapter = pager;
        viewPager.PageSelected += ViewPager_PageSelected;
    }

    private void ViewPager_PageSelected(object sender, ViewPager.PageSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        var viewPagerDotsLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.viewPagerCountDots);
        for (int i = 0; i < viewPagerDotsLayout.ChildCount; i++)
        {
            ImageView dotImage = (ImageView)viewPagerDotsLayout.GetChildAt(i);
            if (i == e.Position)
                dotImage.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ViewPagerDotSelected);
            else
                dotImage.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ViewPagerDotUnselected);
        } 
    }
}


public class ViewPagerAdapter : FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{
    int numberOfFragments = 3;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager fm) : base(fm)
    {

    }
    public override int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return numberOfFragments;
        }
    }

    public override Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment GetItem(int position)
    {
        switch (position)
        {

            case 0:
                return new Fragment1();
            case 1:
                return new Fragment2();
            case 2:
                return new Fragment3();
            default: return new Fragment1();
        }
    }
}
```

Run it and see if it works...

Comment: Yes that worked perfectly. Thank you for your step by step explanation. It was perfectly clear what to do. Thank you very much for your effort.

Comment: Works perfectly.