# Xamarin.Forms view for Wizard

Tags: xamarin.forms, wizard

Is there any View on Xamarin.Forms to use like wizard? I must use Xamarin.Forms (not Xamarin.Android). Any suggestions?
I have seen this post but it looks like a bit complicated to me ([Xamarin step by step wizard android views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38962977/xamarin-step-by-step-wizard-android-views))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update 17.04.2019:

Beginning with Xamarin.Forms 4.0, [there is a new CarouselView control](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-4-0-feature-preview-an-entirely-new-point-of-collectionview/)! This makes my old answer obsolete.

---

**Old answer (obsolete):**

The closest to what you're looking for is a [CarouselPage](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/carousel-page/). It holds several pages and you can navigate between them by swiping the screen to the left or the right.

Unfortunately, `CarouselPage` doesn't contain indicators which show on which page you are right now. You will have to implement this on your own if you need it. Your best choise are [Custom Renderers](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/).

Comment: @kostas Don't use CarouselPage (per Xamarin recommendation). use CarouselViewControl from CarouselView.FormsPlugin which has page indicator.